# Linux sort and cut multiple columns

Tags: sort, cut

I have the following file named "info":

```
White:73:Mars:1543:Manuel
Green:17:Jupiter:1968:Sebastian
Blue:24:Venus:1970:Anna
Red:35:Neptune:1122:Javier
Yellow:135:Earth:1234:Raymond
```

I need to use `cut` and `sort`, to show only the columns with planest and names, sorted. This means I have to be left with:

```
Earth:Anna
Jupiter:Javier
Mars:Manuel
Neptune:Raymond
Venus:Sebastian
```

I tried using
`cut -d: -f3,5 info | sort -t: -k1,1 -k2,2`
but it only sorted the first column and not the second.

I also tried
`cut -d: -f3,5 info | sort -t: -k1,1 -k2,2 | sort -t: -k2,2`
but this only sorted the second column.

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting columns Individually:

```
paste -d: <(cut -d: -f3 info | sort) <(cut -d: -f5 info | sort)
Earth:Anna
Jupiter:Javier
Mars:Manuel
Neptune:Raymond
Venus:Sebastian
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the result consists of two individually sorted columns of data, there need to be two calls to `sort`, each one with a separate set of data.

The [answer of nezabudka](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677324/493832) shows how one may do that in a shell that understands process substitutions:

```bsh
paste -d : \
    <( cut -d : -f 3 info | sort ) \
    <( cut -d : -f 5 info | sort ) \
    >outfile
```

The above assumes that you want to save the output to a file called `outfile`.

In a shell that does not understand process substitutions (you mentioned no specific shell in the question), one may do this in two steps using an intermediate file:

```bsh
cut -d : -f 3 info | sort > outfile.tmp
cut -d : -f 5 info | sort | paste -d : outfile.tmp - >outfile
rm outfile.tmp
```

The first pipeline creates the initial column of the sorted names of planets.  It redirects the sorted data to the file `outfile.tmp`.  The second pipeline creates the second column in a similar manner to the first and appends it to the first using `paste`.  We then delete the intermediate file.

Answer (score 0):

Using [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) and it's builtin array sorting function, we only need a single pass through the file.

```bsh
gawk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = ":" }
  {
    planet[NR] = $3
    name[NR] = $5
  }
  END {
    asort(planet)
    asort(name)
    for (i=1; i <= NR; i++) print planet[i], name[i]
  }
' info
```

Answer (score -1):

```
step1: awk -F ":" '{print $3}' inpfile | sort -k1.1 >out.txt; awk -F ":" '{print $5}' inpfile |sort -k1.1 >out_1.txt

step2: paste -d ":" out.txt out_1.txt
```

output

```
Earth:Anna
Jupiter:Javier
Mars:Manuel
Neptune:Raymond
Venus:Sebastian
```